# Axis2 - client throws "Transport error 401 - Unauthorised" when using at the same time Proxy and Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, proxy, apache-axis, http-status-code-401

We are doing a client that connects to a server service. To do that, we started with the **[Axis2 Quickstart Guide](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html)** (just in case the link changes in the future, its the **StockQuoteService** example). And added the following:

- Connect to a Server (that means, the endpoint reference doesnt point to localhost)
- Use **authentication**

```java
      // Authentication:
      HttpTransportPropertiesImpl.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportPropertiesImpl.Authenticator();
      
      auth.setAllowedRetry(true);
      auth.setUsername("wsuser");
      auth.setPassword("wspass");
      
      options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
```

- Use **Proxy**

```java
      // Proxy:
      HttpTransportProperties.ProxyProperties proxyProperties = new HttpTransportProperties.ProxyProperties();
      
      proxyProperties.setProxyName("255.255.255.255");
      proxyProperties.setProxyPort(0000);
      proxyProperties.setUserName("proxyuser");
      proxyProperties.setPassWord("proxypass");
      
      options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.PROXY, proxyProperties);
```

**The problem is:**

- If we use only proxy (with authentication disabled in the server), it works.
- If we use only authentication and comment the proxy properties, it works too.
- But if we use both at the same time, we get this:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(AbstractHTTPTransportSender.java:386)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPTransportSender.invoke(AbstractHTTPTransportSender.java:214)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:431)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:399)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:150)
    at qt.axis2Clients.StockQuoteServiceStub.getPrice(StockQuoteServiceStub.java:153)
    at qt.axis2Clients.StQuClientAdb.getPrice(StQuClientAdb.java:105)
    at qt.axis2Clients.StQuClientAdb.main(StQuClientAdb.java:75)
```

The problem happens when we try it with a http and with https. With a web browser we can access the service without problem (after writting the proxy and server users and passwords). But somehow our client cant do that. We suppose there are two possibilites:

1. We forget to set something in the options.
2. There is a problem in Axis2 when we set both things.

The user and password are also correct. We dont know why it doesnt work and what else do we need to get this. The authentication is simple, not NTML Also, we dont use certificates in the client. As said, if we run this without proxy but with basic authentication, it works. The problem is when both are present.

This is the complete code we are trying to run (Again, the StockQuoteServiceStub comes from the [Axis2 Quickstart](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/quickstartguide.html). There are also the contents of the last functions):

```java
  public static void main(java.lang.String args[]) {
    try {
      // set Path to certificates:
      TrustStore.assureJssecacertsFile();
      TrustStore.setTrustStoreProperty();
      
      // Set path to 'axis.xml':
      File   axis2Xml = new File("static/webapps/axis2/WEB-INF/conf/axis2.xml");
      String absPath  = axis2Xml.getAbsolutePath();
      System.setProperty(Constants.AXIS2_CONF, absPath);
      
      // URL:
      StockQuoteServiceStub stub = new StockQuoteServiceStub(
          "https://"+ urlToServer +"/axis2/services/StockQuoteService");

      // options:
      Options options = stub._getServiceClient().getOptions();
      options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, false);
      
      // Authentication:
      HttpTransportPropertiesImpl.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportPropertiesImpl.Authenticator();
      
      auth.setAllowedRetry(true);
      auth.setUsername("wsuser");
      auth.setPassword("wspass");
      
      options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);

      // Proxy:
      HttpTransportProperties.ProxyProperties proxyProperties = new HttpTransportProperties.ProxyProperties();
      
      proxyProperties.setProxyName("255.255.255.255");
      proxyProperties.setProxyPort(0000);
      proxyProperties.setUserName("proxyuser");
      proxyProperties.setPassWord("proxypass");
      
      options.setProperty(HTTPConstants.PROXY, proxyProperties);

      // execute:
      getPrice(stub);
      update(stub);
      getPrice(stub);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.err.println("\n\n\n");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end we weren't able to solve this problem with Axis2 and had to migrate the client to Jax-WS.

As far as I know the server uses still Axis2 to serve the web services.